# UIProgressView corner radius not working correctly

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm creating a view programmatically, which has a UIProgressView subview.
The UIProgressView is defined as:

```
progressView = new UIProgressView();

progressView.Style = UIProgressViewStyle.Bar;
```

Then the superview of the progressView is added:

```
Add(superView);
```

And in ViewDidLayoutSubviews I'm trying to make its corners round:

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
        base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

        foreach (UIView subview in progressView.Subviews)
        {
            subview.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
            subview.Layer.CornerRadius = progressView.Frame.Size.Height / 2;
        }

        progressView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.White.ColorWithAlpha(0.3f).CGColor;
        progressView.Layer.BorderWidth = 1f;
        progressView.Layer.CornerRadius = progressView.Frame.Size.Height / 2;
        
}
```

The problem is that the corners are not rounded at this stage, but if I click the home button on the device and then get back to the app, then the corners will be round as expected.

What should I change in order for it to work?

Comment: Hi, I have checked in my local site, it works. Could you share the sample project link? I will check that.

Comment: Yes, this code should work, I've used it before. But in this scenario, from some reason it doesn't.
What solved it was subclassing UIProgressView and making these changes in LayoutSubviews()

Comment: Okey, therefore using `LayoutSubviews` is the workaround? If so, you could update it in answer.